# How to import my external Style or JS files in Astro Layout

Tags: javascript, css, import, frameworks, astrojs

Does anyone know how I'll be able to import my external CSS and JS files into Astro's new version? I tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href={Astro.resolve('../styles/style.css')}>
```

But it's not workings anymore after Astro's new 1.0 Update launch.

Comment: Do you need to load the script from a CDN?

Answer (score 2):

`Astro.resolve` has been deprecated as you can see in detail in the [documentation](https://docs.astro.build/en/migrate/#deprecated-astroresolve).

Summary of the recommended ESM Import method:

1. Place you `.css` file inside the `src/` directory
2. Import it in your `.astro` file:

```
---
// Example: Astro will include and optimize this CSS for you automatically
import './style.css';
---
<html><!-- Your page here --></html>
```

3. Astro detects these CSS imports and then builds, optimizes, and adds the CSS to the page automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you place your style sheet in the `public` folder, you can simply import it using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
```

Comment: Minor correction:  for public folder put /index.css

However I am looking how to use Javascript which is kept in public folder as I am getting the following message:

Please add the "is:inline" directive to keep this asset from being bundled.